# EF Core: ValueGeneratedNever() vs. not using this method at all

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

What is the point of explicitly telling entity framework not to generate a value for a field in a database? There are two other options which are `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` or `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` that make sense but does the framework by default generate a value so I have to disable it manually through that method? If it does not, what is the `ValueGeneratedNever()` exactly for and what is the advantage of it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example, when you want to have manually assigned primary keys, you need to call this method. By convention, EF will assume that primary key properties are automatically generated.